# JMeter testing SOAP web service programmatically

Tags: jmeter

Using JMeter APIs, I tried to call a SOAP web service programmatically. 
    After executing the service, when I checked the web service server logs, no transaction / entry is made over there. It seems the SOAP request did not send to the server at all. But, when I tried to invoke the web service directly using SOAPConnection call() method, with out JMeter APIs, it is working fine and server could generate logs.

Could any one please check it out and correct me on sending SOAP requests using JMeter APIs?

```
My full source code is as follows:

JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("JmeterHome");
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("JmeterHome\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.initLogging();
JMeterUtils.initLocale();


HashTree testPlanTree=new HashTree();



HTTPSampler httpSampler=new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler.setDomain("domain");
httpSampler.setPort(<port number>);
httpSampler.setProtocol("http");
httpSampler.setPath("/wsdl");
httpSampler.setMethod("GET");
httpSampler.setName("Webservice Sampler");
httpSampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);

HeaderManager headerManager=new HeaderManager();
headerManager.add(new Header("SM_USER", "xyz@abc.com"));        
headerManager.add(new Header("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
headerManager.add(new Header("SOAPAction","http://example.com:<port number>/services/MyWebService?wsdl"));
httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);

HTTPArgument httpArgument=new HTTPArgument();
httpArgument.setValue(<SOAP Message>);      
httpSampler.addTestElement(httpArgument);


LoopController loopController=new LoopController();
loopController.setLoops(1);
loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
loopController.setFirst(true);
loopController.initialize();


ThreadGroup threadGroup=new ThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setNumThreads(5);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

TestPlan testPlan=new TestPlan("Web Service Operations Test Plan");
testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
testPlanTree.add("threadGroup",threadGroup);
testPlanTree.add("httpSampler",httpSampler);
testPlanTree.add("loopController",loopController);


SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream("jmeter_api.jmx"));

Summariser summary=null;
String summariserName=JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summary = new Summariser(summariserName);
}

String reportFile = "report.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summary);
logger.setFilename(reportFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);

jmeter.run();

System.exit(0);


I am getting the following output in the Jmeter log file:
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished:  1-1 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done:  1-3 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished:  1-3 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done:  1-4 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished:  1-4 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done:  1-5 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished:  1-5 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2017/01/10 19:50:14 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =      5 in 00:00:02 =    3.1/s Avg:   877 Min:   780 Max:  1088 Err:     0 (0.00%) 


The following results captured on result file:
2017-01-10 19:50:13.070,894, Webservice Sampler,200,OK, 1-2,text,true,,35016,0,5,5,887,0,0
2017-01-10 19:50:13.070,1088, Webservice Sampler,200,OK, 1-1,text,true,,35016,0,5,5,1082,0,0
2017-01-10 19:50:13.466,813, Webservice Sampler,200,OK, 1-3,text,true,,35016,0,3,3,806,0,0
2017-01-10 19:50:13.666,780, Webservice Sampler,200,OK, 1-4,text,true,,35016,0,2,2,776,0,0
2017-01-10 19:50:13.866,811, Webservice Sampler,200,OK, 1-5,text,true,,35016,0,1,1,802,0,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going not recommended way of creating a JMeter test, check out [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html#building) to learn how to do it using JMeter GUI.

If for some reason you need to create a SOAP request programmatically, you can get a known good test plan hashtree structure by calling [SaveService.loadTree()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.html#loadTree(java.io.File)) method passing an existing .jmx script as a parameter so you will have a reference test plan in your debugger which you can re-create using JMeter API.

You can find an example of adding a Header Manager to the HTTP Request [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui#comment-2898624712)

In any case I would strongly recommend to double check that the script is doing what it is supposed to be doing via [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or with a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/)

Comment: Many thanks Dmitri. I followed your suggestions and now I am able to hit the web service programmatically.

Comment: I think the request headers are not properly attached to the request. I am getting the following log exception:

Comment: logException = java.lang.RuntimeException: Unauthorized access: could not find userId in input request.

Comment: I have added the request headers as follows:

Comment: HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler=new HTTPSamplerProxy();

HeaderManager headerManager=new HeaderManager();
Header headerSmUser=new Header("SM_USER","xyz@example.com");
Header headerContentType=new Header("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
Header headerSoapAction=new Header("SOAPAction","http://example.com:xxxxx/MyWebService?wsdl");
headerManager.add(headerSmUser);
headerManager.add(headerContentType);
headerManager.add(headerSoapAction);
httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);

Comment: nope, you can check the example of adding a Header Manager programmatically at https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui#comment-2898624712

Comment: Dmitri, Many more thanks to you. It is perfectly working now.

Comment: HTTPArgument httpArgument = new HTTPArgument();
    httpArgument.setAlwaysEncoded(false);
    httpArgument.setMetaData("=");
    httpArgument.setValue(<<SOAP XML string>>);

Comment: See httpArgument.setValue(<<SOAP XML string>>); line. Whether the approach will work for setting SOAP message with the request? Dimitri, please check and let me know. Please correct me if I am wrong.